# How to pass values from bat file to DB2 sql file using CLP

Tags: sql, windows, batch-file, db2, clp

I need to update Customer table in chunk of 50K, The number of records in customer table is 2 million.

I am using DB2 command prompt to execute my sql from a file using bat file.

There are two file which I have created.

**1. customerupdate.bat**

```
DB2 CONNECT TO DBTEST USER DB2ADMIN USING XXXXXX
set start=%1
set end=%2
db2 -l D:\vinu\CUSTOMERADDRESS.log  -mstf D:\vinu\CUSTOMERADDRESS.sql
```

**2. customer.sql**

```
update customer set firstname='XXXX' where customercid between 1 and 50000
```

Here I need to pass **1 and 50000 value from command prompt**.

update customer set firstname='XXXX' where customercid between **1** and **50000**

I am executing above sql using below command successfully, However I need pass the parameter to sql file.

C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN>**customerupdate.bat 1 50000**

Please note: I cannot use the query directly like

**db2 -l D:\vinu\CUSTOMERADDRESS.log  -mst " update customer set firstname='XXXX' where customercid between %1 and %2"**
The query should be supplied from a sql file only.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do that with the traditional CLP, but it's possible if you use CLPPlus.

In your **customer.sql**:

```
update customer set firstname='XXXX' where customercid between &1 and &2;
exit
```

Invoke CLPPlus (it connects using JDBC):

```
clpplus -nw db2admin/password@hostname:port/dbtest @customer.sql 1 50000
```

`&1` and `&2` will be substituted with the first and second command line arguments respectively.

Comment: My current DB2 version is DB2 v9.5.301.436 seems, CLPPlus is not supported. As per DB2 documentation it is supported after V9.7

Comment: You can download the 9.7 client and use it with DB2 9.5.

Comment: This works for me, I have downloaded client from, http://plutonium.cs.umanitoba.ca/downloads/DB2_client/

Comment: I suggest you obtain the DB2 client software from the official download site: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27016878

Answer (score 1):

Rather than putting all of your SQL in a separate SQL file, why not just include the statements in your batch file?

```
DB2 CONNECT TO DBTEST USER DB2ADMIN USING XXXXXX
set start=%1
set end=%2

set FIRSTNAME=Vinu

db2 -l D:\vinu\CUSTOMERADDRESS.LOG "update customer set firstname = 'XXXXX' where customercid between %start% and %end"
```

This will require a little more error checking (since you can't rely on the `-s` flag for the CLP to stop execution), but it will work.

Comment: I already mention this option in my post.

db2 -l D:\vinu\CUSTOMERADDRESS.log -mst " update customer set firstname='XXXX' where customercid between %1 and %2" The query should be supplied from a sql file only.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear:  I gave this alternate solution to @mustaccio's precisely because, you can't do what you're asking via the DB2 CLP.

Comment: We can upgrade the client from below link and using CLPPlus command we can execute the script from sql file.    http://plutonium.cs.umanitoba.ca/downloads/DB2_client/